# How to Extend SNMP Agent with Custom Bash Script, Custom Enterprise OID and Custom MIB

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I am looking for a tutorial/guide to help me create a custom oid ( with my own enterprise number in the oid ), custom MIB using a variable base script in snmp Agent. Most of the examples I see on the Internet like

[24.6.5. EXTENDING NET-SNMP](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sect-system_monitoring_tools-net-snmp-extending)

[Tut:Extending snmpd using shell scripts](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Tut:Extending_snmpd_using_shell_scripts)

uses the method in which the result from the scripts are found in OIDs like 
`.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.*`

which means if I run

```
$ snmpwalk -v2c -c testing 127.0.0.1 nsExtendOutput1
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line."test" = STRING: hello
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutputFull."test" = STRING: hello
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutNumLines."test" = INTEGER: 1
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendResult."test" = INTEGER: 0
```

what I want is the OID should include my custom Enterprise number. How to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, After a lot of research, I came up with a detailed guide on how to achieve this. have a look at https://github.com/ahmednawazkhan/guides/blob/master/snmp/creating-custom-mib.md

Comment: How to implement read-write mib's?